# Show that the limited domain of a complex function spans the entire codomain

Tags: complex-analysis

The problem:

> Let $z=x+iy, w=u+iv$ complex numbers and $w(z)=z+e^z$ an analytic complex function. If $y \in [-\pi, \pi]$, show that $w(z)$ spans the plane $w=(u,v)$.

I've seen a demonstration that uses a family of curves in the given interval, but I was wondering if it is possible to show this by using orthogonal vectors, I mean, is it possible to transform this problem into a linear algebra one where I could show that any point from the plane $w=(u,v)$ is a linear combination of the vectors that compose the original transformation $(x,y)\mapsto (u,v)$?

My attempt was something like:

$$v_1=x+e^xcos(y)$$
$$v_2=y+e^xsin(y)$$
In order for $\vec{v_1}=(v_1,0),\vec{v_2}=(0,v_2)$ to span the entire plane $w=(u,v)$, they need to be orthogonal, $\vec{v_1}\cdot \vec{v_2}=0$. But I could develop any further than that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I've adjusted the text accordingly.

Comment: That's where I'm stuck. I just can't write something like $\vec{k} \in w=(u,v), \vec{k}=\alpha\vec{v_1}+\beta\vec{v_2}$, I don't know how to justify this.

Comment: Actually, the image is the set of all $(v_1,v_2)=(x+e^x\cos y,y+e^x\sin y)$.  The question is then if every point in the plane can be written that way.

Comment: Scratch my first comment.

Comment: I was not sure if I could just use the fact that they're independent, 'cause y is limited to $[-\pi,\pi]$. Not completely clear on how to bypass that limitation.